# What does the logic operator "not" mean in EL

Tags: jsp, el

Given the following code:

```
<%
java.util.Map map = new java.util.HashMap();
request.setAttribute("map", map);
map.put("a", "true");
map.put("b", "false");
map.put("c", "42"); 
%>

${not map.c}
```

the output of `${not map.c}` is true.... what kind of operation is this expression? and why the result from it is true?

Answer (score 3):

The specification says:

> Unary not operator - {!,not} A
>
> - Coerce A to Boolean, apply operator

and

> Coerce A to Boolean
>
> - If A is null or "", return false
> - Otherwise, if A is a Boolean, return A
> - Otherwise, if A is a String, and Boolean.valueOf(A) does not throw an exception, return it
> - Otherwise, error

`map.c` is the string `"42"`. `Boolean.valueOf("42")` is `false`, and the `not` operator applied to `false` returns `true`.